# Laravel DB::select($query)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project that does custom SQL commands from input. I have the following functions.

Route

```
 Route::patch('/form-submit', function(Request $request){
  $query = $request->input('query');
  return view('welcome', compact('query'));
});
```

Welcome.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/form-submit" class="text-end">
   {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
   @csrf
   <input name="query" value="{{ $query }}" id="input" class="form-control w-20">
   <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info mt-3">Submit</button>
 </form>

<?php
  $querys = DB::select($query);
?>
```

Now I want to loop through all the values that the SQL command gives me.
For example, for the input "SELECT * from users" I will get all the users and I can show their name using:

```
@foreach($querys as $data)

  {{$data->name}}

@endforeach
```

But I would like to show all the data for the user, including name, sex, id, age, etc. I tried multiple options but I didn't find yet a solution. The query will always be different so I will not know what data do I have to show. For example, if I type "SELECT * from notifications" I want to add all the informations from the database in a table.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: where is the query you are executing? where is the code

Comment: the code is in the blade, I have an input with name query: <input name="query" value="{{ $query }}" id="input" class="form-control w-20">

Comment: show the code where you are calling the query ... which should not be in a view

Comment: I updated now the code

Comment: you know this is a horrible idea right? to take a sql query directly from a user and run it against the database

Comment: Please don't do this on a public facing environment as people will be able to drop tables and databases

Comment: I will not to it on a public environment, I do it for my website so work easily

Comment: If it's for your usage alone you're better off using a regular dbms

Answer (score 1):

You can return array from Model use `->toArray()` method and then you will have associative array. You can do something like that

```
@foreach($querys as $field=>$value)

<p> {{$field}} = {{$value}} </p>

@endforeach
```

Where `$field` it's field name in table and `$value` it's column value. Also you need check nesting, if you have several results

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error: tmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Yes if you have a several result, you will have array where all element is object. So you need two loop,  in the second loop you can get your results

Comment: This is what I meant about nesting. I think you should do you query then parse result in your service (or where you have business logic) and then return result array to your template

Comment: It works, But now I can get just the values. For example for user with {"id":2,"name":"user2"} I can show just 2 and user2. Any idea on how can I show also id and name?

Comment: Do you use loop like this `@foreach($querys as $field=>$value)` ? Here `$field` must be your keys `id` and `name`